# Set responsive image at center page above the table cross-line

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4, responsive

```
#logo-center {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:991px) {
    .logo-div {
        -webkit-margin-start: -5%;
        -webkit-margin-end: -15%;
        -webkit-margin-before: -6%;
        left: 40%;
        top: 40%;
        right: 40%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        display: flex;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:990px) {
    .logo-div {
        -webkit-margin-start: -5%;
        -webkit-margin-end: -15%;
        -webkit-margin-before: -6%;
        left: 40%;
        top: 42%;
        right: 42%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
    .logo-div {
        left: 38%;
        top: 43%;
        right: 40%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
    .logo-div {
        left: 35%;
        top: 42%;
        right: 40%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
    }
}
```

```
<div class="logo-div">
            <div id="logo-center"><img style="border-radius: 7%;" src="https://www.crockerriverside.org/sites/main/files/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg"></div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8rmL5a7f/
I need to resize image at center (so to be responsive in mozilla/chrome/ie)) and set it at the center of page to cover the cross where the table border meets. 
My code works only on firefox, but not in chrome or IE. 
Anyone can help me to know why?

Comment: At `#logo-center img` add `width:100%;` and `height:auto;` That's it! On my tests worked. If yes, let me know to post as an answer to you could check as the right answer.

Comment: Ok, i was failing. It's worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't set the width of the image and your image is really big they overflow the wrap div.

Do this:

```css
#logo-center img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

The `height:auto` will keep the ratio of the image.

On my computer (Windows) at chrome **before**:

[image]

On my computer (Windows) at chrome **after**:

[image]

---

**To centre image in the div:**

You will need to **make the `.table-responsive.bordered.fill` and `.logo-div` the same `width` and `height`** and than:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container .logo-div {
  postion: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And please delete the `right` property on `.logo-div`.

Basically, the `top` and `left` 50% will align in the middle but considering the borders. To put in the middle considering the centre of element you will need to use `transform: translate` top -50% and left -50% because this will move back based on the child element (.logo-div) size and not the parent (#container) or the border of the child.

*PS: You can do it with a negative margin or flexbox (justify-content and align-items on centre). But I normally use this presented solution with translate.*

Comment: Thank you so much again!

Comment: Is there a way to get center image responsive and anchored to center when window is resized? (without left: 40%; top: 42%; right: 42%; -webkit-margin-start: -5%; etc)

Comment: @simone_meh I update the answer with the solution for it. Please have a look and if it works, upvote the answer.